# Less4j, unable to use custom functions as path variables

Tags: java, less

i'm trying to user custom functions in less4j that brings back common paths for use in css:

```
com.github.sommeri.less4j.Less4jException: Could not compile less.   
ERROR style.less 94:27 Unable to evaluate expression

details summary {
94:     background-image: url(common()/img/ic_g_down.png);
95:     background-position: left center;
```

Function is:

```
public class ConstantLessFunction implements LessFunction {

  private static String fs[] = {
      "common",
      ...
  };

  @Override
  public boolean canEvaluate(
      FunctionExpression call, List<Expression> parameters) {
    return ArrayUtils.contains(fs, call.getName());
  }

  @Override
  public Expression evaluate(
      FunctionExpression call, List<Expression> parameters, 
      Expression evaluatedParameter, LessProblems problems) {
    String name = call.getName();
    switch (name) {
      case "common":
        return new IdentifierExpression(call.getUnderlyingStructure(), "/common/images/");
        break;
        ...
    }
}
```

I used IdentifierExpression because of the examples on wiki.

Maybe another way to do so, like adding variables in java to compiler or something like this.

Thanks, Phaedra.

Comment: You can't use functions like this (either built-ins or custom, i.e. a function call is not a string so you can't concatenate its result with another string like `foo()bar`). For your example you first need to assign the function call result to a variable and only then concatenate this variable with the rest of string, e.g. `@some-path: common();` then `background-image: url("@{some-path}/img/ic_g_down.png");` (or `background-image: url(@{some-path}/img/ic_g_down.png);` depending on whether syntax is supported by less4j).

Comment: maybe a better way to do this is to inject variables via java into less4j context when compiling sources, is this possible?

Comment: No, idea (at least I can't see anything like `--modifyVars` in `less4j` [command line options](https://github.com/SomMeri/less4j/wiki/Command-Line-Options)). Alternatively you could add a paramater to your `common` function so it can be used like `background-image: url(common(img/ic_g_down.png));` (though it could require moving the `url` part into the function as well). And another way would be to use [`%`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions--format) function, e.g. `background-image: %(~'url(%a/img/ic_g_down.png)', common());` or so.

Comment: finally, i've decided to create vars at the start of my css using: @common: common(); and so background-image: url("@{common}/..."); thanks!